# Downgrade to Lion from Mountain Lion OS

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

One of my friend bought his MacBook Pro with preinstalled Mac OS X Lion (10.7.2). Afterwards, he installed the Mountain Lion (10.8) developer preview in it.

He wants to downgrade the OS to Lion (10.7). One option I see is using the Lion recovery suggested at http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718.

But, he had not purchased Lion before as it was preinstalled on his MacBook Pro. Does he need to purchase Lion now from the App Store while in the recovery mode OR if he doesn't have to buy it, will he get it free?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's why they say not to install the Developers Preview on your daily machine (as only OS...)

Nevertheless, not having the a Lion disk isn't a obstacle. You should do fine with a decent backup and [Lion Recovery Disk Assistance](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1433).
If you follow these [7 easy steps](http://macolyte.net/post/17821725406/how-to-downgrade-from-the-mountain-lion-developer), your friend will have his Lion back in no-time.

Comment: Can he upgrade to full-fledged Mountain Lion OSX 10.8 which is coming this July.? I am asking this because in prerequisites they have mentioned that updated Snow Leopard and Lion Users can upgrade.

Comment: As long as your friend has Lion (or Snow Leopard) and pays for Mountain Lion, he'll be perfectly capable of upgrading to it without any issue.

Comment: Absolutely, but if he will not downgrade the OS to the Lion and stick to the developer preview of the Mountain Lion then in such case can he upgrade to Mountain Lion?

Comment: If he is a real, legitimate developer (which I doubt more and more...) he'll have to stick with the Golden Master of Mountain Lion which is practically the same as the final release.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, he is just pass-out graduate from the college and started learning IOS. :)

Comment: Hmm, if he's learning iOS, he's downloading the wrong developers preview! Either way, which him good luck!

Comment: Yes you are right, I will convey your message to him. And one lesson I also learnt from this is never go for anything without taking proper precautions.